# How do I control the color of list item bullets?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble selecting and styling a navigation on my friends site. Screen shot:
[image]
Those red dots between the items? The list style type is none but they are still showing. Rather than remove them I'd like to change their color, right now they appear red. I could not see any CSS that controls these, nor could I figure out what selector applies to them.
How can I select and control those dots between the nav items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is pseudo class styling applying on each `a` tag, if you have a look at the inspection tools, select the `a` anchor tag and right down below it within the element nodes you'll see `::after` which shows the Pseudo styling

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.main-navigation .nav-menu > li > a:after, .main-navigation .menu > li > a:after{
color: #ffa4ad;
content: " \2022";
margin-left: 1em;
}
```

I'd recommend tracing that in your stylesheet.

The color property is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `li` elements a `class` or an `ID` and then use CSS to change the color

for example

Consider following HTML

```
<ul class="listStyle">
    <li id="test">
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
    <li id="test1">
        <p><strong>View :</strong> blah blah.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with CSS

```
#test {
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: black;
}
```